# Creating Sqlite3 database using in-memory option

Tags: sqlite

I am using latest **Sqlite version 3.8.3.1** on Ubuntu host.
Here i am trying to create in-memory database in using c program and the option explained in the following link: http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Here database is created using following function call:

```
sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared", &db);
```

Here database file `file::memory:?cache=shared` is created on hard drive locally.
Here why sqlite3 is creating database file on the hard drive for in-memory option?

Let me know if i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[URI filenames](http://www.sqlite.org/uri.html) work only with [sqlite3_open_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html).

Comment: Tried using the following function call  sqlite3_open_v2(":memory:?cache=shared", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL ); After using above function call also it is creating ":memory:?cache=shared" file on the Hard Disk. Is anything wrong in my usage?

Comment: If I enable only SQLITE_OPEN_URI flag then i am getting following error: Can't open database: out of memory. And If i put all the flags SQLITE_OPEN_URI | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE then database is created and also it creates following file on hard drive :memory:?cache=shared

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake earlier i had specified incorect URI. Now with "file::memory:?cache=shared" URI it is working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this to create database on RAM.
It's the in-memory implementation supported by python

`import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')`